# ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I need an Activity in my BroadcastReceiver, but when i try to cast the context to activity, it doesn't work.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

How can I get Activity from BroadcastReceiver ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I get Activity from BroadcastReceiver ?

Generally, you can't. A BroadcastReceiver is independent from an Activity. For example, you can have BroadcastReceiver which receive broadcasts when no Activity is running.

You can, however, register/unregister a BroadcastReceiver in an Activity and use it to receive broadcasts while your Activity is running.

Comment: Thank you but how can i do for register/unregister it ?

Comment: Using [registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)).